# load jquery only basic part, not all unwanted code of jquery

Tags: jquery, google-closure-compiler

I want to find out about the jquery basic loading. I do not want to load the whole jquery. Because we do not needed whole jquery everytime. Below are my queries.
1. Is it possible to load some basic jquery and then load as requirement. If possible than suggest me the steps or some tutorial.
2. It has something like Google closure library. In google closure library you can add only needed namespace and only that part will load when we compile it.

Comment: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ maybe

Answer (score 0):

Check out zepto js, might be what you are looking for http://zeptojs.com/

Comment: it seems good. Can you show me the use of zapto with jquery. Also it has same functionality as jquery or different??

Comment: I think you are supposed to use it instead of jquery, I've only used it with jquery mobile. I found this guide on how to replace jquery with Zepto, might be of some help to you http://mikefowler.me/2013/09/26/replacing-jquery-with-zepto-backbone/

Comment: Zepto seems good. But require retest and rewrite our code. Means no component based loading for jquery is available.